# PHP fput can't upload file

Tags: php

I'm having some difficulties with uploading files on one app. Application is  using procedural php and it's really old, but everything is working fine.
So the problem is, I'm uploading some smaller file and it's says that upload is not succesful, but it is uploaded. But I can't upload some bigger file, for example 10mb.
This is the file for checking upload.

```
else if ($_GET['task']=="uploadfile") {

    $serverid = $_POST['id'];
    $file['path'] = $_POST['path'];
    $file['upload'] = $_FILES['file'];

    if ($gpanel->isDemo($_SESSION['clientid'])) {
        $_SESSION['notification'] = _ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE_FOR_DEMO;
        header("Location:gp-webftp.php?id={$serverid}&path={$_POST['path']}");
        die();
    }

    if ($gpanel->FTPuploadFile($serverid,$file)) {
        $_SESSION['notification'] = "Uspesan upload !";
        header("Location:gp-webftp.php?id={$serverid}&path={$_POST['path']}");
    } else {
        $_SESSION['notification'] = "Neuspesan upload !";
        header("Location:gp-webftp.php?id={$serverid}&path={$_POST['path']}");
    }
```

And this is the function

```
function FTPuploadFile($serverid, $file) {
        global $mysql;

        ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

        set_time_limit(0);
        ini_set('post_max_size',"100M"); 
        ini_set('upload_max_filesize',"100M");
        ini_set('max_input_time', 3000);
        ini_set('max_execution_time', 3000);

        $serverid = (int)$serverid;
        $clientid = $_SESSION['clientid'];

        $tmp = $file['upload']['tmp_name'];
        $fp = @fopen($tmp, 'r');

        $naziv = $file['path']."/".$file['upload']['name'];

        $server = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($mysql->db, "
        SELECT `server`.*,`box`.`ip` AS `boxip`
        FROM `server`
        LEFT JOIN `box`
        ON `box`.`boxid`=`server`.`boxid`
        WHERE
        `server`.`serverid`='$serverid' AND
        `server`.`clientid`='$clientid' AND
        `server`.`webftp`='on'
        "));
        if ($server['serverid']=="") $this->serverGreska($serverid, _ERROR_SERVER_NO_WEBFTP_ALLOWED);

        $ftp_connection = ftp_connect($server['boxip']);
        @ftp_login($ftp_connection, $server['user'], $server['password']);
        @ftp_pasv($ftp_connection, true);
        ftp_set_option($ftp_connection, FTP_TIMEOUT_SEC, 600000);

        ftp_fput($ftp_connection, $naziv, $fp, FTP_BINARY);
          // FTP_ASCII , FTP_BINARY
        //  return true;
        //} else {
        //  return false;
        //}

    }
```

What could be a problem?

Comment: If you're trying to debug a script, you should get rid of the `@` in case there are relevant warnings.

Comment: When I remove it's all the same.

Comment: Where does it say that the upload is not successful? I don't see any error checking in the code. If it fails, I would expect it to print a warning message with the reason.

Comment: Now, when I try to upload, it's giving error anyway. How to check what is the real reason?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: With this code, always error that file is not uploaded but it is, only bigger files can't be uploaded.